# Why does Wordpress not permit svg image files by default?

Tags: wordpress, security, svg

Why can't I upload SVG image files to Wordpress(4.2.2) by default? when you try you get the message:

> Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

I know this problem has been around for a while, and I've used this solution in the past, from https://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/allow-svg-through-wordpress-media-uploader/, :

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

But what are the security implications of allowing this behaviour and why has it been disabled by default?

Answer (score 2):

SVG files are fairly rich in that they contain XML and even JavaScript. As such, the processing of these files is [riskier](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11384/exploits-or-other-security-risks-with-svg-upload) than processing simpler image formats.

Comment: Thanks Neil. That was my hunch. I was hoping for a more concrete answer with an example that could be applied to Wordpress. I accept the link highlights some potential vulnerabilities which could be applied to Wordpress, but IMO they're not that well explained and would require more investigation to understand. So, while your answer is clearly correct and helpful, I'd like a little more on how SVG exploits could be damaging.  I imagine someone could write something malicious and recursive and pop some javascript inside the SVG? But how would this be done?

Answer (score -2):

> SVG image type not showing in wordpress

```
function my_media_types($media_types){
    $media_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'; 
    $media_types['psd'] = 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop'; 
    return $media_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_media_types', 1, 1);
```

by defalut wordpress not support svg because svg conveted to xml file when you can set .svg image than it's all data as a xml format for security reason wordpress not allow by defalut svg or site hacked by xml file because xml show all data

Comment: This answer is completely incomprehensible.